# Tired after a few sets

Tags: bodybuilding, strength-training, bodyweight-exercises, muscle-soreness

Ive noticed recentky that i my muscles get pretty fatiqued after some few sets of working out. For example since i train with high intensity and a 5x5 programm i do all my sets to failure.

So lets say i do weighted pullups. Ive noticed after my second set to failure my back is like stuck on. Im full pumped but my reps are gradually decreasing where by my last set i can barely do 2 . Like my back is stuck and wont move. Anyone knows why this happens and what to do to avoid it?

Comment: Are you doing 5x5 or are you doing all of your sets to failure? Because those aren’t really the same thing.

Comment: Your muscles will get very fatigued if you're doing 5 sets to failure, and you'll be able to complete substantially fewer reps at the same weight by the fifth set. This is absolutely unavoidable. If you want to be able to recover between sets and repeat the same number of reps, then don't train to failure.